# gcc std option and linker option in code

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++, compiler-options

I switch between so many projects and IDEs a lot. They run each project with default options of IDE. For example

```
g++ test.cpp
```

I know `make file` can solve the problem. But it is not IDE friendly way. I am thinking if there is any way to impose option

```
-std=c++11
```

In the code rather than in calling g++.

The same problem with linker. I want to tell the linker in the code that I want to link to armadillo library

```
-larmadillo
```

Maybe setting a prepossessing command could solve the problem. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)? With this you can create compiler and IDE independent makefiles and then generate the makefiles/project files for the environment of your choise. You can freely script it so you can set certin swithces for gcc and other for vc++ or clang.

You can also use it if you want to create different build configurations.

Comment: I would instead suggest simply to learn GNU make (*without* using `cmake` to generate `Makefile`-s)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That is also a possible solution, but maybe insufficient. CMake can generate Visual Studio project files for example. (Although it is not specified in the question what IDE he wishes to use.)